# Clone layout from another drawing then viewports are lost after save in AutoCAD .NET

Tags: autocad-plugin

When I clone a layout from another drawing exported from Revit and then save it. After reopen the file, the viewports are lost. Can you please help me with this issue?

```
  private void CopyContent(ObjectId newLayoutId, Layout cloneLayout)
   {
       Document mdiActiveDocument = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
       Database database = mdiActiveDocument.Database;
       using (Transaction transaction = mdiActiveDocument.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
       {
           Layout newLayout = newLayoutId.GetObjectAs<Layout>();
           using (BlockTableRecord blockTableRecord = cloneLayout.BlockTableRecordId.OpenAs<BlockTableRecord>())
           {
               List<ObjectId> list = blockTableRecord.OfType<ObjectId>().Where(id => id.IsFullyValid()).ToList();
               if (list.Any())
               {
                   ObjectIdCollection objectIdCollection = new ObjectIdCollection(list.ToArray());
                   IdMapping idMapping = new IdMapping();
                   database.WblockCloneObjects(objectIdCollection, newLayout.BlockTableRecordId, idMapping,
                       (DuplicateRecordCloning)4, false);
               }
           }

           transaction.Commit();
       }
   }
```

[Before saving the file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE98G.png) /
[After saving the file and reopening image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8iQh.png)

I tried to Audit and purge the project but it did not help.
The viewport should not be lost after saving the file.